# Doctrine - Comma separated values in field

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to implement Doctrine on top of legacy MySql database. For now it wokrs kind a great. But...

I have **Events** table whitch has following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- skipped ---
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `category` text,
)...
```

And table **Categories**, whitch has categories. Structure is like...

```
CREATE TABLE `tx_tendsical_category` (
  ...
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ...
)
```

Now... Category IDS are **stored as comma (,) separated values** in events.category field. How can i setup relations without much hassle... I need hasMany etc...

Comment: You'd be better off normalizing to give yourself an Events_categories table

Comment: I can't because i'm only implementing "view" system, database can't be changed :(

Answer (score 3):

If you are having problems with database schema, write your own hydrators. When you'll have all data fetched, parse it and return proper object collections.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way... Perhapse there is better way?

```
public function getCategories(){
    return Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from("Category c")
        ->where("c.uid IN ?",array(explode(",",$this->category)))
        ->execute(array(),Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ON_DEMAND);
}
```